# momentjs does not return the correct date format

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, momentjs

I am referring momentjs library for nodejs and the my code looks like below

```
console.log("For date:" + item.DueDate + " the format is:" + moment(item.DueDate).format("do, MMM"))
```

The output for above is

```
For UTC date:2020-07-28T00:00:00.000+0000 the format is:2nd, Jul
```

i am confused why 28th july is printed as 2nd jul ?

i have also tried:

```
moment(item.DueDate).utc().format("do, MMM")
```

but same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `do` (day of **week** with ordinal) instead of `Do` (day of **month** with ordinal).

To quote the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

> ```
> Day of Month  D       1 2 ... 30 31
>               Do      1st 2nd ... 30th 31st <<<<<<<< THIS IS WHAT YOU WANTED
>               DD      01 02 ... 30 31
> [...]
> Day of Week   d       0 1 ... 5 6
>               do      0th 1st ... 5th 6th <<<<<<<<<< THIS IS WHAT YOU USED INSTEAD
>               dd      Su Mo ... Fr Sa
>               ddd     Sun Mon ... Fri Sat
>               dddd    Sunday Monday ... Friday Saturday
> ```

Therefore, try `moment(item.DueDate).format("Do, MMM")` instead.

Comment: let me check this one.